# Emacs shell isn't opening correctly

Tags: shell

I have just installed Emacs, but when I try to open the shell, this error comes up:

```
emacs: /usr/bin/fish: No such file or directory
Process shell exited abnormally with code 127
```

I used to have fish as Terminal in my computer but I removed it long ago.

Comment: sounds like it's using an evironment variable to get the shell name. ESHELL maybe?

Comment: How can I modify that environment variable?

Comment: use env command in your system shell to see what's defined to start with. If you use bash you can define it in `.profile` or `.bash-profile` or the other files stated in the manual.

Comment: Thanks!!! :) It works!

Comment: Please write an answer describing what it was and what you did to solve it. Comments aren't indexed.